# How to access the raw capacitance image on an Android device

Tags: android, security, sensors, android-sensors

I get stuck on how to get the capacitance image out of an android phone. Is it necessary to Hack the android system to get the capacitance image in Android?

In the released Android API, it only allows me to get which point an finger is touching on the screen. But since the touchscreen is using capacitive sensing, I am wondering how can I get the raw capacitance sensing data from the system? I guess I may need to hack the system for further information. Does anyone have done it before? Or give me some hints or directions on where I should start with?

Comment: Have you found a way?